# Paramiko authentication to server with no password fails

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am connecting to a host which runs dropbear and has a blank root password. I can connect to it via `ssh` (I have replaced the actual IPv6 address and host name here):

```
$ ssh root@[2001:db8:1234::567]
root@my_host:~# ps aux | grep dropbear
root      2481  0.0  0.1   2408   504 ?        Ss   06:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/dropbear -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -B -p 22 -P /var/run/dropbear.pid
root      4492  1.2  0.2   2876   992 ?        Ss   08:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/dropbear -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -B -p 22 -P /var/run/dropbear.pid
root      4637  0.0  0.1   2344   556 pts/0    S+   08:35   0:00 grep dropbear
root@my_host:~# exit
Connection to 2001:db8:1234::567 closed.
```

When I try to do this with Paramiko, it throws an `AuthenticationException`. This is my minimal example script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(
    "[2001:db8:1234::567]",
    port=22,
    username="root",
    password="",
)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\src\minimal\minimal.py", line 8, in <module>
    client.connect(
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 435, in connect
    self._auth(
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 766, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 753, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1563, in auth_password
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 258, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

Any ideas why the authentication with Paramiko fails?

---

Verbose `ssh` output:

```
$ ssh -vvv root@2001:db8:1234::567
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/config
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 2001:db8:1234::567 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 2001:db8:1234::567 [2001:db8:1234::567] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2017.75
debug1: no match: dropbear_2017.75
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 2001:db8:1234::567 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5
debug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:2oIgeSG/smq4GNl7z1jLMBEaMw4peSXOWGZlW9aZUaY
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
The authenticity of host '2001:db8:1234::567 (2001:db8:1234::567)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:2oIgeSG/smq4GNl7z1jLMBEaMw4peSXOWGZlW9aZUaY.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '2001:db8:1234::567' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none).
Authenticated to 2001:db8:1234::567 ([2001:db8:1234::567]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:850 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 24576 rmax 32759
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
root@my_host:~#
```

Paramiko (2.9.2) log

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xbfd81bb0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.9.2
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-dropbear_2017.75
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client dropbear_2017.75)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange possibilities ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server key: ssh-rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client encrypt: aes128-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-cbc, aes256-cbc, twofish256-cbc, twofish-cbc, twofish128-cbc, 3des-ctr, 3des-cbc
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server encrypt: aes128-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-cbc, aes256-cbc, twofish256-cbc, twofish-cbc, twofish128-cbc, 3des-ctr, 3des-cbc
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client mac: hmac-sha1-96, hmac-sha1, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-md5
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server mac: hmac-sha1-96, hmac-sha1, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-md5
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client compress: zlib@openssh.com, none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server compress: zlib@openssh.com, none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex follows: False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange agreements ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey: ssh-rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== End of kex handshake ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for [2001:db8:1234::567]: b'0366f1abed7f1a4625c3abd6185944bf'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\src\minimal\minimal.py", line 12, in <module>
    client.connect(
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 435, in connect
    self._auth(
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 766, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 753, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1563, in auth_password
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "C:\Users\username\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 258, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71750537/9235421) already states the cause. The dropbear server does not use any authentication at all. In order to implement the workaround with `Transport.connect` and still have a `paramiko.SSHClient` to interact with, we can do the following (thanks to [ttimasdf](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/890#issuecomment-906893725))

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paramiko

host = "[2001:db8:1234::567]"
port=22
username="root"
password=None


client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
# Workaround for no authentication:
# https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/890#issuecomment-906893725
try:
    client.connect(host, port=port, username=username, password=password)
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
    if not password:
        client.get_transport().auth_none(username)
    else:
        raise e

# Now we can interact with the client as usual
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls /")
lines = stdout.readlines()
print(lines)
```

Comment: Is there a way to confirm we are actually connected after the line `client.get_transport().auth_none(username)`? Like what if the device is actually offline? Will it throw another exception?

Comment: @cwbusacker If the host device is offline, you will not even get as far as authentication. Instead of `paramiko.SSHException` it's better to use the specific `paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException` to try the passwordless authentication. And then also a handle a bunch of other exceptions which can happen. I encountered TimeoutError, ConnectionAbortedError, paramiko.SSHException's payload {"Error reading SSH protocol banner", "No existing session", ...} paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError, (on Windows:) OSError 10013, 10051, and others: look for windows-sockets-error-codes-2

Comment: only `except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:` as an line of except does work for me. `client.py/_auth()` raises an `SSHException`, therefore to catch this is the closest approach imo.

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like you authenticate with a blank password. You actually do not authenticate at all to the server (technically, `ssh` uses "none" authentication method).

Paramiko `SSHClient` does not try that method automatically.

You have to explicitly code it by using a low-level `Transport` class with its [`Transport.auth_none`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.auth_none) instead of the high-level `SSHClient`:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport('example.com') 
transport.connect()
transport.auth_none(username)
```

---

*The above code implicitly bypasses host key verification (what your original code does explicitly by using `AutoAddPolicy`). That's a security flaw. Use `hostkey` argument of the `Transport.connect` to correct that.*

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about the security flaw with the AutoAddPolicy. One should always verify the authenticity of the host. However, the dropbear server from my above example is configured such that it changes its host key everytime it is rebooted. It's a device in a test infrastructure, so we only connect to in a controled test environment. Hence the auto-add policy.